# convex function on open interval

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I have a quick question. If a continuous function $f$ is convex on $(a,b)$, then the following is true? Could you explain why or why not it is true?

$for \,\,x\in(a,b)$, $t=\frac{x}{b}<1$

Thus,

$f(ta + (1-t) b) \leq tf(a)+(1-t) f(b)$

by the convexity of $f$.

In short, can I apply the convex property on the boundaries of the domain of the function?
Thanks in advance

Comment: See if you can prove this, using the fact that $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $b$.

Comment: It depends, if your function is continuous on $[a,b]$, then yes, if not, the inequality is false in general. For instance, take $f(a)=f(b)=-\infty$.